# Different results using parallelism despite there being no data dependency/data race?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, dependencies, openmp

I have a piece of code in C which generates an int matrix and assigns 0 to every field. Afterwards, when I run this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            a[i][j] = a[i][j] + 1
```

without OpenMP, I get, as expected, 1s in every field.

But when I run it in parallel, I get plotches of random values (0s and sometimes even 2) every once in a while, despite (what I think is) a piece of code with no data dependency. Everytime it's ran, it produces a different result with different plotches of messy values. Am I missing something? I made sure that it's the same code by simply writing it in serial first, then copying it over and just adding the extra lines making it parallel. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: We could *guess* at the *kind* of issue you might be having, but we cannot actually answer the question based on the information provided.  Our usual expectation for debugging questions such as this is that they provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I reproduced the issue by running the same code on less threads - it's really random. When I run the code on more threads, I found that the values spike all the way up to 3-4 (on 4 threads). For the spiked values, I can assume that the spiking values are the result of multiple threads accessing the same elements for some reason and running the addition multiple times, but that doesn't explain the 0s. Everytime it's ran, the location of the different values is different.

Comment: Your `'j` variable is shared and so, yes, you will have a race condition. You can either make `j` private, or better: declare loop variables in the loop header. (Seriously, who teaches this way of declaring all variables in the main?)

Comment: @VictorEijkhout That's what I didn't consider!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @pron1ghtmare360, "minimal reproducible example" means you present (just) enough code for *us* to reproduce the issue.  The link in my previous comment goes to a rather full explanation of that, including suggestions for how to prepare one.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout legacy C code I guess... In Academia there is also a lot of researchers doing programming classes with very outdated information. If you spend all your life with legacy code bases and only visit conferences for your field of study (e.g. physics) you don't get a lot of contact with modern software engineering principles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `i` and `j` variables aren't declared inside the parallel pragma.

According to http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/ this can cause the `j` variable to be shared across all parallel threads, meaning it gets incremented too many times and rows get skipped (causing 0's).

I suspect with the right ordering this also causes increments to be lost (causing 2's, 3's and 4's), but I'm not sure what order that is off the top of my head.